# showing the scrollers in scrollview and webview

Tags: iphone, webview, scrollview, scrollbars

I am using scroll view and web view in my application. I want the vertical scroller has to visible wether in scrolling or without scrolling. have to display the scroller permanently.

is it possible?

if possible, plz help me.

thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

> Important: You should not embed
>   UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so,
>   unexpected behavior can result because
>   touch events for the two objects can
>   be mixed up and wrongly handled.

Read this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

i am not embedding UIWebView in UIScrollView.

i am using UIWebView only.

- if the content is more than the
  webview frame then i have to show the
  vertical scroller for the webview.

  if the content is fit in the webview then no need to show the scroller.